# Haven't ECMA5 (recent JavaScript) any built-in function for copying objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

I need something like Ext.apply in Node.js. The most obvious way is to define my own:

```
function simplestApply(dst, src1) {
  for (var key in src) if (src.hasOwnProperty(key))
    Object.defineProperty(dst, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, key));
}
```

But isn't there any built-in function for the same purpose?

Comment: `Function.apply` ? its build-it in V8, and thus in Node.

Comment: No. Function's apply() is quite different thing for different purpose, than Ext.apply() and simplestApply() above.

Comment: ah, you want something like `merge` ? - then no, there is nothing like that in vanilla js. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically or `jQuery.extend()` or `Object.append()` (MooTools).

Comment: Thanks. I just found built-in features for some framework-powered utils, like `bind`. I thought it could be something for merge|extend|append|apply too.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest way, but it doesn't copy the functions.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: This method does not apply properties to an existent object. It is a way to clone JSON-like tree. But it is fast, that's true. About 3 times faster than `simplestApply({}, obj)` according my tests.

Comment: You can do this, too.

`var b = {};
for (var i in a) {
  b[i] = a[i];
}`

It is faster: http://jsperf.com/object-copying